# Win 10 IoT + apache + php + mysql + ssl?

Tags: windows-iot, php, mysql

I'm looking for an easy way to get on Win10 webserver based on apache (or familiar), php, mysql, and ssl (all 3 must have). Everything I found on google has no info how to do it... only how to change something or how to provide new things.

Comment: Windows IoT is supposed to be used a thin client. The PHP, MySQL and SSL should live on a real server. There are ways to do what you want but not using the stuff you want to use.

Comment: You just need to someone port PHP source code to win 10 iot

Answer (score 2):

Everything you assume from traditional Windows systems is irrelevant in IoT Core. Wintel binaries like apache.exe , php.exe and mysql.exe are positively unwelcome and simply won't work.

Windows 10 IoT core is best regarded as vehicle to run one (1) full-screen Universal Windows Platform App all the time - there is no Desktop , no explorer.exe and definetely not multiple Windows - **by design**. Also there is no regard to backwards compability - **by design**. 90 % of the worlds Windows software (including WAMPP and relatives) doesn't work on it  - **by design**.

Raspbian can transform into a solid LAMP (Linux , Apache , MySQL , PHP) system with one apt-get invocation - **by design**.

Comment: I can't use Raspbian (don't ask why...). I know Raspbian can become LAMP, because I've done it. But right now I need to have the same on Win10 IoT.

Comment: Buy an Intel Compute Stick or a real PC. You will get nowhere with Win10IoTCore + Raspberry Pi if you want (X)AMP.